# How can I stop the shell command `mate` from opening Textmate 1.x instead of Textmate2?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, textmate

I've installed `mate` in the preferences pane in TextMate2. It says "Shell support installed." I added the string `export EDITOR="/usr/local/bin/mate -w"` to `~/.bashrc` as instructed.

However, when I use the `mate` command, Textmate 1 launches, for example if I type `mate test.txt` in the Terminal. I would like it to launch TextMate2.

Ideally, I'd like to keep TM1 around, as it does a few things that TM2 doesn't yet do. But if scrapping TM1 is the only/best option, that'd be useful to know, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace the symlink path in /usr/local/bin/mate to Textmate2

```
//go to the bin directory
cd /usr/local/bin

//delete the existing symlink
rm -rf mate

//create the symlink to the Textmate 2 mate executable
ln -s /Applications/TextMate2.app/Contents/Resources/mate mate
```